# Convert AdHoc select queries to SQL views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am working on a legacy database application that is strewn with adhoc SQL statements all over - many of them repeated at multiple places. I feel that I should be moving all these adhoc statements into views so that I can re-use the code, write tSQlT unit tests for the view and make the code base more maintainable.  Are there any overheads to maintaining a lot of views in a SQL Server DB?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.  There can be a maintenance cost, however that should be less than the maintenance cost of the system as currently described.